# Send object from servlet to jsp and back to servlet

Tags: jsp, session, jakarta-ee, object, servlets

how do I send an object back to Servlet (from JSP), when I received the very same object from another Servlet in a session?

Here is the code:

1) user = object (Loginservlet -> succes.jsp)

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
```

2) Receiving userobject in success.jsp

```
User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
```

3) Now i want to send this object to ExchangeServlet, because I need some properties of this object, like user.getUsername(), but the object is not reachable anywhere in the JSP page, only where I receive it.
I want to send it when clicking on a button for instance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you mean by **not reachable anywhere in the JSP page, only where I receive it**, a session variable should be visible all the time until session timeout or session closed(user logout for instance).

Comment: when I do like <% user.getUsername() %> somewhere in the JSP page it says "cannot find symbol" and highlights "user"

Comment: I will try something, one second. May have solved it

Comment: I'm sorry there was something really strange. I couldn't reach the object in the rest of the xhtml. Now I can. Thanks anyway!